# Почему библиотеки изменились?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Изучаю книгу "Head First. Программирование для Android". Там написано, что для того, чтобы на старых устройствах появлялись возможности из новых версий android выпускают библиотеки поддержки. Например **v4 support library** можно поставить на android API 4 и выше. Для того, чтобы посмотреть какие библиотеки установлены советуют посмотреть File→Project Structure. У меня из библиотек 1) appcompat 1.4.0 2)constraintlayout 2.1.2 3)material 1.4.0. Я правильно понимаю, что эти библиотеки заменили старые v4 support library, v7 support library? И я могу выполнять примеры из книги с помощью библиотеки appcompat 1.4.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В целом - да всё верно. Библиотеки помянутые в вашей книге уже пару лет как устарели и не используются. Вместо них - библиотеки из пакета androidx. Разработка под андроид меняется так быстро, что нет порой смысла читать книгу с датой выхода (текущее время минус год). Т.к. книгу начинают писать задолго до выхода в печать и перевода на русский.